# Summation of limit using integrals

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}}......+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+2x)}}$$ This is the given problem now I tried approaching it with definite integrals as sum of limit so $$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{x.\sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{x^2})}}$$ but to make it integral r and x should be of same power so possibly this method would fail so how to proceed this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting

$$\sqrt{1+\frac n{x^2}}=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{x}\right)^2}$$

**Edit:** What about trying a way that *actually* works? Let us apply the squeeze theorem:

$$2\xleftarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{2+\frac1n}{\sqrt{\frac2n+1}}=\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{2n+n^2}}\le\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac1{\sqrt{k+n^2}}\le\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{2n+1}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 2$$

Comment: But then how will be substitute integral variable ? r/n is substituted as variable , how will $\sqrt{r}/n $ be substituted

Comment: You're right, this doesn't help, though the algebra is correct. I got confused by your use of symbols: $\;x\;$ is usually the variable's name whereas $\;n,m,k\;$ are usually reserved for the running index (over the naturals).

Comment: @Tesla, check the edit I've just made.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x$ must be an integer. The terms in each sum $S_x$ are a decreasing family hence $$\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\leqslant S_x\leqslant\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x^2}},$$ which is enough to deduce that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}S_x=2$.